# How do I populate my OrderItem model with fields from my Product model in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am using ModelViewSet and serializers to view my orders and products.
So in my admin panel for my Product model I already added product, price, and price per pound. So eg. (banana, 2.00, 2.99).

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    price_per_pound = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

In my OrderItem model I can select the product that is available, but when I select the banana I want the price and price_per_pound fields to auto populate with what I have in my Product model eg.(2.00, 2.99). How would I go about this?

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(Product.price) # Tried this way, but doesn't work.
    price_per_pound = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='product_price_per_pound', on_delete=models.CASCADE) # this still only give me the field names of my product
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    ready = 1
    on_its_way = 2
    delivered = 3
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (ready, 'ready'),
        (on_its_way, 'on its way'),
        (delivered, 'delivered'),
    )
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

Comment: Why would you want to store the price and price_per_pound in OrderItem if you have a foreign key to your product that already has this information? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to display the price and price per pound fields when someone is trying to order a product so it shows like a model view. Is that bad? Or is it not possible?

Comment: That's not a good idea. It's better to add extra fields to the modelserializer of OrderItem that reference the fields in the product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done best by writing a custom model serializer for your `OrderItem` class and adding a field that points to the `price` field through the foreign key `product` like this:

```
class OrderItemSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    price = DecimalField(source='product.price')

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = ('price', 'quantity')
```

You just need to add more fields from your model to the `fields` attribute of the `Meta`class if you need them. For the `price_per_pound` field you would make a similar field like `price`. Finally you should configure your viewset to use this serializer.

If you were to add the fields to the model class instead, you would be duplicating your data and have it in 2 places in your database. You usually want to avoid this.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help.